# Problems installing Appium, cannot install dependency opencv4nodejs, dead locked

Tags: android, node.js, npm, appium, appium-android

Okay I do have a Linux Laptop
and I want to install "appium" on it ...
root@Falkenstein:~# uname -a
Linux Falkenstein 5.4.0-70-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 19 13:29:52 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**The Appium Doctor is quite happy except that opencv4nodejs cannot be found :-)**

carlos@Falkenstein:~/Android$ appium-doctor --android
info AppiumDoctor Appium Doctor v.1.16.0
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic for necessary dependencies starting ###
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ The Node.js binary was found at: /usr/bin/node
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Node version is 10.19.0
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ ANDROID_HOME is set to: /home/carlos/Android/Sdk
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ JAVA_HOME is set to: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
info AppiumDoctor    Checking adb, android, emulator
info AppiumDoctor      'adb' is in /home/carlos/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
info AppiumDoctor      'android' is in /home/carlos/Android/Sdk/tools/android
info AppiumDoctor      'emulator' is in /home/carlos/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ adb, android, emulator exist: /home/carlos/Android/Sdk
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ 'bin' subfolder exists under '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64'
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic for necessary dependencies completed, no fix needed. ###
info AppiumDoctor
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic for optional dependencies starting ###
WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ **opencv4nodejs cannot be found**.
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ ffmpeg is installed at: /usr/bin/ffmpeg. ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ mjpeg-consumer is installed at: /usr/local/lib. Installed version is: 2.0.0
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ bundletool.jar is installed at: /home/carlos/Android/bundletool/bundletool.jar
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ gst-launch-1.0 and gst-inspect-1.0 are installed at: /usr/bin/gst-launch-1.0 and /usr/bin/gst-inspect-1.0
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic for optional dependencies completed, one fix possible. ###
info AppiumDoctor
info AppiumDoctor ### Optional Manual Fixes ###
info AppiumDoctor The configuration can install optionally. Please do the following manually:
WARN AppiumDoctor  ➜ Why opencv4nodejs is needed and how to install it: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/image-comparison.md
info AppiumDoctor
info AppiumDoctor ###
info AppiumDoctor
info AppiumDoctor Bye! Run appium-doctor again when all manual fixes have been applied!
info AppiumDoctor
carlos@Falkenstein:~/Android$

**So I became root and tried to install opencv4nodejs but it didn't work :-( **

root@Falkenstein:~# npm i -g opencv4nodejs

> opencv-build@0.1.9 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/node_modules/opencv-build
> node ./install.js

info install if you want to use an own OpenCV installation set OPENCV4NODEJS_DISABLE_AUTOBUILD
info readAutoBuildFile file does not exists: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/node_modules/opencv-build/opencv/auto-build.json /usr/local/lib/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/node_modules/opencv-build/opencv/auto-build.json
info install failed to find auto-build.json: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/node_modules/opencv-build/opencv/auto-build.json
info install
info install running install script...
info install
info install opencv version: 3.4.6
info install with opencv contrib: yes
info install custom build flags:
info install
info install executing: git --version
info install git --version: git version 2.25.1
info install
info install executing: cmake --version
info install cmake --version: cmake version 3.16.3
info install
info install CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
info install
info install installing opencv version 3.4.6 into directory: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/node_modules/opencv-build/opencv
ERR! Error: Command failed: mkdir -p opencv
mkdir: das Verzeichnis »opencv“ kann nicht angelegt werden: Keine Berechtigung

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! opencv-build@0.1.9 install: `node ./install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the opencv-build@0.1.9 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-03-30T11_47_39_084Z-debug.log
root@Falkenstein:~# ^C
root@Falkenstein:~#

So I became bold and created the missing folder myself:
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/node_modules/opencv-build/opencv

But it seams to be removed when I install again.